# Remove last item when looping each query rows

Tags: php, mysql, csv, foreach

I'm creating a csv file through a PHP script that goes through the results of a query.

The rows I get when I do:

```
foreach $result as $row
```

look like this:

```
$row
array (
  'id' => '9',
  'description' => 'a nice book',
  'product-title' => 'Book title',
  'references' => '4044782308578',
  'id_bookstore' => 2,
)
```

So far so good.
My problem is that 'id_bookstore' I ask the database to do some operations, not to include it in the csv file.

But if I don't include 'id_bookstore' in the csv file in `fputcsv($file, $row, ';');` I get an error (the number of elements in the header doesn't match the number of elements in $row)

Do I have to remove the 'id_bookstore' => 2 in each row from $row to avoid the error? If so how?

Or is there another way to solve it?

Here the code:

```
$file = fopen(book.csv, 'wb');
$delimiter = ';';

fputcsv($file, array("id", "description", "product-title", "references"), $delimiter);

foreach ($result as $row) {
    
        fputcsv($file, $row, ';');
}

fclose($file);
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Can you show the actual PHP code used to generate the CSV file as this is usually important in being able to answer a question.

Comment: Edited the post and added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to remove 'id_bookstore' from the row just use unset function like below:

```
$file = fopen(book.csv, 'wb');
$delimiter = ';';

fputcsv($file, array("id", "description", "product-title", "references"), $delimiter);

foreach ($result as $row) {
        unset($row['id_bookstore']);
        fputcsv($file, $row, ';');
}

fclose($file);
```